# Visual Studio 2013 Code Coverage- Binaries not being instrumented

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, code-coverage

I am trying to run code coverage on my blocks of code using test that I have written. Before it was working fine but now I get the error:

> Empty results generated: No binaries were instrumented. Make sure the tests ran,  required binaries were loaded, had matching symbol files, and were not excluded through custom settings. For more information see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=253731

I cannot seem to figure out how to solve this. Looking around I see that many people have tried going to their project root directory and deleting the .suo (solution user options) file there, but that did not solve my problem.

**I am using VS 2013 Ultimate**

Comment: What edition of VS are you using? (professional/premium, etc)

Comment: I am using VS2013 Ultimate. Edited original post to state that.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty difficult to give a 100% correct answer here so I'll just tell you what I would do in your shoes.

First off, create a brand new solution and project, with some `hello world` code, and see if you can get the code coverage to work in that. If it works then you know it's something wrong with your original solution and/or projects, rather than your VS configuration.

One way to find out what's gone wrong would be to use source control to find when it stopped working. Try getting an old version of your codebase, and see if the code coverage is working in that version. If it works in that version then you could continually get different versions of your codebase until you find a version it doesn't work in. Once you've converged on 2 versions where it works in one and fails in another, you'll then be able to check the differences between the 2 versions to find the reason it broke.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to make changes in your test project. eg. add new test or comment existing one. In my case it helps.